# Can I stop an Uruk from inviting all his friends to the party?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I'm currently trying to work out how to kill my nemesis, who's survived death twice. I *nearly* got him a third time, but he keeps calling in reinforcements, multiple times. While I've managed to thin the herd, its pretty hard to kill someone with quick life regeneration (and a ton of other buffs) while I'm trying also needing to deal with an ever increasing cloud of lackeys.

Is there any way I can interrupt a Uruk calling in reinforcements in Shadow of Mordor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can try is taking him down with **FEAR**

It works pretty well. You just have to find a way of fearing him and he will become weak!

Easy to grab and easy to kill!

For the strat I would first check if he has any **Vulnerabilities**:

> **Vulnerable to Stealth Finishers** - Can be killed instantly using
>   stealth  finishers;
>
> **Vulnerable to Combat Finishers** - Can be killed instantly using
>   combat finishers;  **Vulnerable to Ranged Attacks** - Can be killed by
>   a  single charged headshot, fire arrow, or shadow strike;
>
> **Vulnerable to Mounted Beasts** - Can be killed instantly by mounted
>   beast finishers;
>
> **Clumsy** - Can be grabbed without needing to lower his health
>   Branded (Once dominated) Can be grabbed without requiring low health

Then, after that I would go for your best bet of winning such a strong opponent! **FEAR**!

> **Fear of Caragors** - Becomes terrified at the sight of Caragors;
>
> **Fear of Ghuls** - Becomes terrified at the sight of Ghuls;
>
> **Fear of Graugs** - Becomes terrified at the sight of Graugs;
>
> **Fear of Burning** - Becomes terrified when burned;
>
> **Fear of Morgai Flies** - Becomes terrified when exposed to Morgai Flies;
>
> **Fear of his Rival** - Becomes terrified when near a potential rival;
>
> **Fear of Betrayal** - Becomes terrified when Uruks fight together (Branded vs. Free);
>
> **Fear of the Gravewalker** - Becomes terrified at the sight of Talion;

Devise your strategy with these things in mind and you will surely kill him.

**EDIT**

Well I think the skill you're looking for is

> **Summoner** - Calls out nearby allies in a fight.

Basically he will always call allies to the fight so your best bet is using AOE attacks.

One really good at high levels is **Wraith Burn**.

So to sum all this up, you can stop him by **killing him (dominating him)** or running away (not that I think you want to do that anyway). And deal with the crowds using the strats I stated above.

Comment: Oh, I do intend to kill him eventually. However, with the stronghold uruks, I just need to shoot someone in the head or otherwise kill him to keep reinforcements from coming in. I'm curious about a *specific* enemy skill and a way to counter that directly if possible

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'm gonna edit my answer

Comment: @JourneymanGeek If you found my answer useful please consider accepting it :)

Comment: I'm not convinced if it answers my question entirely. You did mention the skill name, but not how to *actually* stop him from calling in allies (or that its not possible)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek basically what I'm saying is that the only way to stop him is killing him or running away. I'll edit to make it more clear.

Comment: Close enough, I guess. I'd note if there's an *actual* way to counter this, I may change my accepted answer. Thats a pretty stinky power to have.

Comment: For the record... I ran unto him at random while hunting for the warchief he was bodyguarding. He didn't call in reinforcements, and he was alone enough that I *finally* managed to take him down. I suspect he didn't have time to. I'll need to confirm that though.

Comment: I've had that happen to me too @JourneymanGeek . Once during a whole fight a summoner uruk didn't call reinforcements once. But we were fighting on a secluded place.

Answer (score 0):

If the Uruk has the Summoner ability, no.

But you can deal with it by using his Fear against him so he runs away - he will leave behind his allies and won't summon more while he is running away. You can then deal with him alone. I recommend using Pinning Shot to stop him (once he gets far enough away from the summoned allies that they aren't a problem) so he doesn't disappear on you.

@Lokuzt did a nice job of summarizing the Fear options.